# What does 之为 mean?

Tags: grammar

For example, in the phrase "教师之为教." I know it is formal language, but what is a good way to understand it in English?

Comment: cf。＂现代汉语词典＂：之³ （２）用在主谓结构之间，取消它的独立性，使变成偏正结构：中国～大｜战斗～烈｜大道～行也，天下为公｜如因势利导，则如水～就下，极为自然。Accordingly 教师之为教 would mean "A teacher's acting as teacher", an endocentric construction 偏正结构 that could be the subject of a complete sentence (see below answer).

Answer (score 3):

I searched for 教师之为教 and got a few hits suggesting it's the first clause from the sentence "教师之为教，不在全盘授予，而在相机引导。……".

In that case, 之 means *of; from* and 为 means *act; perform*.

教师之为教 literally means 'the act of teaching of a teacher (should be ...)', and in this context means 'the art of teaching (is ...)'.

> 教师之为教，不在全盘授予，而在相机引导。
>
> The art of teaching is not to explain everything at once, but to guide at opportune times.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, not enough points.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this 之 just 的？ Edit: that is to say 之为 is not a word it's more 教师-之-为-教

教师的为教 The teacher's way of teaching ...

A strange phonetic coincidence between 为 and way!

Comment: in agreement with other answer and comment

Comment: Yes, I also agree, since it came from ancient Chinese, to somebody it looks rather difficult to understand at first sight, but it's in fact quite easy, to get a better understanding it's suggested to split them up, 之 simply as 的, at some degree similar to the genitive case. 为, as a linking verb, translated as BE, here a gerund would be a proper choice, so the literal translation would be "the teaching of a teacher".

Answer (score 0):

imo, "教師之為教" is an composed verse, pretending in old written style. so, here's the literary chinese approaches:

first, some examples of "之為":

```
一之為甚
```

once (一) is (為) too much (甚)

之 indicates the occurrence of "once", while 為 is "being"

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000149553

```
知之為知之，不知為不知
```

understanding (知之) is (為) understanding (知之)

之 indicates the state of understanding

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000113233

```
佛之為教﹒以神為貴
```

buddha (佛) 's (之為) doctrine (教), or

the doctrine (教) of (之為) buddha (佛)

```
師之為理﹒在於發悟
```

teachers (師) ' (之為) principles (理), or

the principles (理) of (之為) teachers (師)

```
so, back to "教師之為教".
```

imo, it's ugly, "not-literary-chines-enough", a better saying is "師之為教".

i would suggest "之為" as **'s**:

teachers (師) ' 之為 teaching (教)

or "之為" as **of**:

the teachings (教) of (之為) teachers (師)

or, a more clumsy one:

the teachings (教) conducted (為) by (之) teachers (師)

since chinese language is fuzzy, there're a few more ways of explanations, the above are just some of them.

have fun :)